# DateTime conversion not working c#

Tags: c#, datetime

**EDIT** I have completely edited the code, since a lot of my strange attempts at fixing the basic error were misleading people to believe there were errors in my code, when it was simply trying any and all apprches to solving the problem. The many myriad of ways I have attempted to convert a perfectly valid, BUILT IN date time format to system datetime object has failed, and don't know why.

**endedit**

I need help, I have literally just ripped some hair out as a result of being unable to solve such a seemingly simple task, trying to convert my date log (a csv, which is reading correctly) to DateTime. the error is in trying to convert my log entries (which when printed, are correctly formatted date times) to DateTime Objects for comparison.

```
EXAMPLE INPUT FROM CSV: 2016-03-22T04:03:31
EXAMPLE INPUT FROM File.GetLastWriteUTC(path): 2016-03-22T04:03:27
```

Both are identical, but I can't convert my csv log entries to `DateTime` for no particular reason.

I have tried any number of formats. I am writing to the console which proves that the dates that I am working with are indeed correct C# compatible date time formats. I have tried DateTime.Parse/ParseExact with every parameter I can find online. I am even trying to remap a new date time to a new format, or converting the string, to date time, back to string with a format, and converting that PROPERLY FORMATTED STRING back to a date time.

And yet, every time I run my program, I'm left with "When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object." And "Make sure your arguments are in the same format", though I have PROVEN that they are beyond a shadow of a doubt the correct format, no missing zero's, and no single quotations. I'm writing out built in formats using the .ToString modifiers, I have went down the list trying f, F o, O, s, S, etc.

Someone please save my sanity. Below you can see a number of my brain fried hackish attempts to figure out why this isn't working, and just when I think I've come up with something clever, GUARANTEEING the correct format, it still fails.

```
        using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace vimbackupscript2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
                watcher.Path = "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\etc";
                watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
                DateTime time = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(watcher.Path + "\\vimrc");
                string logPath = "C:\\Users\\USERPROFILE\\vimbackup\\log.csv";
                var logFile = File.ReadAllText(logPath).Split(',');

                foreach (var log in logFile)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDateTime(log));

                }

                watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

                watcher.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.All);

                File.WriteAllText(logPath, time.ToString("s") + ",");
            }

        }


    }
```

}

Comment: Give an example of your input date and output

Comment: Do you happen to know about **Custom** DateTime format? It might be a good choice for you...

Comment: I have converted to several custom date time formats, and tried various "Cultures" for DateTime.ParseExact. I mean, I'm using BUILT IN formats, and it doesn't recognize the format??

Comment: Is the error in `result < time` line or in the `var result = Convert.ToDateTime()` line?

Comment: the error is in trying to convert my log entries (which when printed are correctly formatted date times) to DateTime Objects for comparison.

Comment: I guess the more direct response is yes var result = Convert... I tried changing it from DateTime to var to see if it would make a difference. It hasn't... Same error

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact("2016-03-22T04:03:31", "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss")` to get the proper DateTime in any culture settings.

There are other issues in your code though. What do you think you can get by converting to datetime, then to string and then to datetime?

If only the comparison fails, clearly the datetime conversion works since you get that far.

You're taking a DateTime in *UTC*, then creating another one based on that in *local* time, so it'll be off based on the timezone offset. Then you do a `ToString()` which does nothing.

So is your actual issue that you mess up DateTime with timezones? Debugger will show easily what the times are.

If you want to compare the DateTimes in local timezone, use `GetLastWriteTime` to get the time.

Comment: Because as i mentioned, i was trying very hacking ways of manipulating the date time into other formats. I could Convert.ToDateTime(log).ToString("S") and it would print the correct format. So why not try converting that format to DateTime. Because Convert.ToDateTime(log) and every variation I've tried doesn't work

Comment: @nanthil Again, clearly it works since *you get a DateTime* and *no error*. And if printing it out gives the correct result, *it works*. See my comments about timezone problem in your code and just print out the values and see *why* the comparison doesn't work.

Comment: Incorrect, it only works when I ....ToString() afterwords. Leaving out the ToString presents me with the same error.

Comment: I have printed out the values of every iteration I've tried, I don't get a date time and no error,  iget an error if I leave it at datetime, if I tostring i get no error. I have attempted to address the timezone "error" and got the same error I got without attempting to rectify timezone.

Comment: @nanthil Could you please just check the datetimes or do you not want help? Talking about an "error" while conversion just works and not showing a single result in the comparison (the datetimes you compare, that is) and how they are "wrong" will not get you any closer. If you don't get a datetime, there is something else wrong since *a datetime can never be without a value*.

Comment: I have shown you the result. The 2 examples are the strings that print out when I tostring the datetimes, and my "time" variable works as a datetime object just find. But when I attempt to convert the log, It errors on that line if I take off .toString(FMT) 2016-03-22T04:03:31, this is the result. I could copy ever other version of .ToString(FMT) out there, but they all work.... when I convert it tostring, as soon as I take it off the end of the statement, it throws an error.

Comment: I'm out of ways to say it. There is no comparison, I can't compare errors, vs won't let you step over an error, and any attempt at converting the log dateSTRING which I've provided a number of times, throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is if you debug the code and examine the number of ticks.
The best solution would be to create a DateTime type in your foreach loop and then compare. i,e `var result = new DateTime(...)`. Ive also posted my test code

[image]

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            {
                //I NEED TO COMPARE THIS TIME WITH THE LAST LOGGED TIME
                DateTime x = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime time = x; //File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(watcher.Path + "\\vimrc");
                DateTime newTimeFormat = new DateTime(time.Year, time.Month, time.Day, time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second);
                time.ToString("O");

                string log = x.ToString();
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDateTime(log).ToString("s"));
                    var result = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(log).ToString("s"));

                    //THIS ERRORS EVERY SINGLE TIME, EVEN WHEN LOG IS CONVERTED TO A 100% VERIFIABLE LEGITIMATE FORMAT
                    if (result < time)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("bleh why don't my conversions work!?!??!!?");
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```